# Does CiviCRM integrate with Raiser's Edge?

Tags: wordpress

We have Raiser's Edge but will we be able to export data to raiser's edge or import data to CiviCRM and dump raiser's edge?

Comment: might be better to change your subject to 'How can we migrate data from Raiser's Edge to CiviCRM' if that is the outcome you need. - And if that is the outcome then i think this is a duplicate of http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9735/how-to-migrate-raisers-edge-data-to-civicrm/9851