# Can I sync CiviCRM data with Raiser's Edge?

Tags: integration, mailchimp

We currently use Raiser's Edge. We're thinking about handling our e-communications via Mailchimp and wondered whether we can then use CiviCRM as the back end to our online functionality and then sync it to Raiser's Edge.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

CiviCRM has a fully-featured "API", which makes it relatively easy to get data in and out of it via a sync.  Raiser's Edge has an API, but it's an additional add-on.

If you had the API add-on for Raiser's Edge, this would be possible - though the more data you want to sync the more intensive the process would be.

Comment: Folks should contact me on chat.civicrm.org (as @junglebird) to discuss specifics of this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to sync or migrate data from Raiser's Edge into CiviCRM. Here are some useful posts that might help you

[How to migrate Raisers edge data to CiviCRM?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9735/how-to-migrate-raisers-edge-data-to-civicrm/9851)

https://civicrm.org/blog/dharmatech/migrating-raisers-edge-civicrm

Comment: I don't think this answers the question - it specified 'synch' but your links are both about 'migrate'

Answer (score 1):

We recently got ImportOmatic to move data into Raiser's Edge from CanadaHelps (an external fundraising site) and I'm working now on using that tool to run regular imports and exports between Raiser's Edge and CiviCRM (we're just starting to use CiviCRM for some things that would be harder or more expensive to do in RE, while maintaining that system for our Fundraisers who love it).

Comment: This is great news Kathryn!  I hope you'll write up your process and publish configurations so that others can do the same, and hopefully contribute improvements back to you.